# How to deny access to url not from server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

How to deny direct access to url with say pattern foo whose referrer is not the site's server with apache mod rewrite (or nginx).

I have the following apache mod rewrite (nginx equivalent also):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (foo/)$ http://example.com [L]

# nginx configuration
location / {
if ($http_referer !~ "^http://(www\.)?example\.com"){
rewrite (foo/)$ http://example.com redirect;
}
}
```

This allow the internal script to access the url with pattern foo, but not directly through the browser. That's what is wanted. BUT..if a user clicks on a link from outside, even if it doesn't have pattern foo, the user receives 404 error. How can I accomplish the following logic:

```
if (pattern == foo and referrer != example) then redirect to example.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers

Comment: That answer doesn't help. I don't want to list a set of okay and not okay referrers. I just don't want direct access to url with foo. Everything else should apply as normal.

Comment: You just need to list valid referers. I guess it's `www.example.com` and `example.com`. What do you mean by "direct access"?

Comment: It is simply that a user should not be able to go to the url: example.com/foo from their browser but the script from the sever of example.com can. I have said in my question that this is fine. The issue is if a link example.com/cat is clicked from some other source (referrer), other than example.com, they will receive a 404 error. Direct access should only be blocked for example.com/foo.

Comment: Probably you need to show full nginx config.